# CSV & Lgstash & Elasticsearch

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, encoding, format, logstash

**I need help !**

I am new in Elasticsearch ... I just imported data in CSV format from Kaggle and I integrated them into elasticsearch via logstash by specifying the configuration file, but on elasticsearch my data is no longer readable (it is in this format: u0000E \ u0000l )
Did I need to add any converts to the config file?

Thank you.

Comment: could you please provide the logstash configuration as well. which will help other to understand what you have configured.

Comment: input {
       file {
          path => "C:/elastic_stack/data/*.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
         }
     }
filter {
        csv {
      separator => ","
   columns => ["id","name","location","description","rating","image","link"]

   }
       }

output {
         elasticsearch {
                        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
               index => "es_hotels"
                       }      
        }

Comment: you file format should be UTF-8 then only it will index properly. you can use codec plugin as well to convert data to UTF-8. here is referance: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-csv.html

Comment: I tried: codec => plain { charset=> "UTF-8" } and ruby { code => 'event.set("decoded", Base64.decode64(event.get("message")))' } but but it didn't  work

Comment: I have a binary data

Answer (score 0):

I tried:     codec => plain { charset=> "UTF-8" }                                                                         and    ruby { code => 'event.set("decoded", Base64.decode64(event.get("message")))' }             but but it didn't work
this is what I get:                                                                            {
"host" => "HIND",
"id" => "\u0000G\u0000u\u0000e\u0000s\u0000t\u0000s\u0000 \u0000c\u0000a\u0000n\u0000 \u0000r\u0000e\u0000l\u0000a\u0000x\u0000 \u0000i\u0000n\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000g\u0000a\u0000r\u0000d\u0000e\u0000n\u0000 \u0000a\u0000t\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000p\u0000r\u0000o\u0000p\u0000e\u0000r\u0000t\u0000y\u0000.\u0000",
"message" => "\u0000G\u0000u\u0000e\u0000s\u0000t\u0000s\u0000 \u0000c\u0000a\u0000n\u0000 \u0000r\u0000e\u0000l\u0000a\u0000x\u0000 \u0000i\u0000n\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000g\u0000a\u0000r\u0000d\u0000e\u0000n\u0000 \u0000a\u0000t\u0000 \u0000t\u0000h\u0000e\u0000 \u0000p\u0000r\u0000o\u0000p\u0000e\u0000r\u0000t\u0000y\u0000.\u0000",
"decoded" => "\x1A\xE7\xAC\xB6\xC7\x1A\x9E\xB7\xA5k\x18\xA7\xB6\x17\xA0j\xB7^\x9D\xABm\x85\xEAk\xA2\x97\xAB\xB7",
"path" => "C:/elastic_stack/data/hotelsb_df_es.csv",
"@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => 2021-08-04T18:04:46.170Z
}